# Removing outliers from a dataset

Tags: python, data-science, visualization, anomaly-detection

I was working on detecting anomalies and removing them. To understand topic better I started to work on a dataset. I used boxplots to see anomalies better and these are the graphs I have.

[image][image]

Also these are values from clean-up code.

[image]

[image]

I wrote the code below in order to print anomaly points and removing them.

```py
for i in feature_list:
    Q1 = np.percentile(data[i], 25)
    Q3 = np.percentile(data[i], 75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    upper = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
    lower = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    anomaly = (data[i] >= upper) | (data[i] <= lower)
    print("Anomaly points in", i)
    print("")
    print(np.where(anomaly))
    data.drop(data.index[anomaly], axis=0, inplace = True)
    print("")
    print("New shape of data after removing outliers:", np.dhape(data))
    print("**************")
```

After removing them I wanted to check graphs again in order to see changes more clearly.

[image][image]

As you can see anomalies in pH column are completely gone but there are still anomaly points in sulphates column. I did not understand why this happened. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I think those outliers are still below your 75 percentile. Try reducing further

Comment: You might be more interested in reading and asking about outliers on the statistics Stack, [Cross Validated](http://www.stats.stackexchange.com). As a professional statistician, I am skeptical about your methodology, but Cross Validated is the place to have such a discussion, not here.